# How do I accept base64-encoded data in JAX-RS (Jersey)?

Tags: java, rest, encoding, jersey, base64

Because there's no ubiquitous support for [sending binaries through XHR (AJAX)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) in browsers yet, I need to send a PNG image in a base64 encoding (with a `Content-Encoding: base64` HTTP header, presumably).

What's the correct way to decode the base64-encoded data on the Jersey's side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use one of the `decode` methods on `com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64`. You can also pull in Apache Commons Codec and use their DigestUtils class, but thats totally unnecessary if you're already using Jersey libraries.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense - I don't know how I could miss the `jersey.core.util.Base64`. :)